How does XRF Work From Beginning to End?
I make a specific point about "beginning to end."
X-Ray Fluorescence, or XRF, is when an X-Ray bombards an atom, and the emitted photon is measured and can identify certain minerals in [crystal] structure.
However, there are some aspects of this process that are just outright stated without explanation: "The X-Ray Beam Intercepts the Entire Atom and Chooses to Excite the Hidden and More State Inner Electrons as opposed to the higher energy electrons that are more easily excited and stripped off."
Further, an electron is stripped off, but nothing explains what actually fills the vacancy left after the higher energy electron fills the spot; an explanation I would use from the photoelectric effect is atmospheric ions stabilize the metal by adding in the missing electrons, but I am not sure if I can say the same thing for XRF. I note this second one was asked about 9 years ago, but the answer is not very clear.
What is actually happening in these two scenarios? Why does the X-Ray Consciously Go inside the Atom, and Does the sample just happen to stay ionized?

You have it all backwards. X-rays don't do anything consciously; they are very stupid, almost as stupid as my cat. As for the sample, no, it does not stay ionized for very long.

But then X-Rays should just excite the first electrons it reaches; it makes a conscious choice to not excite the less stable outer electrons.

I know I sound absurd but that is the point; I also how an atom can remain as an ion, as it would have to lose its ionicity at some point. The explanation offered just does not add up in my mind.

First, there is no "first". An X-ray wave engulfs an atom all at once and can interact with any electron. And so it does; it is just that the ionization of outer electrons does not bother us when we speak of XRF. Second: the ions will recombine after some time, what can be unclear about that?

The X-rays happily excite any and all electrons in the sample. Characteristic emission is easier to measure the higher the energy of the outgoing X-ray, so those are the key ones to look for. Most excited electrons remain within the sample so the sample doesn’t charge significantly, and is usually grounded anyway.

At this rate please make an answer please :3; never studies electrics, so what is meant by "grounded"? And...are you saying that all electrons in an atom are excited when bombarded, but that only the excitation in lower electrons is a noticeable signal? Why do explanations always say the lower level electron is ejected if they do not even leave the atom?

They do leave the atom. But not the sample.

@IvanNeretin Do you have a link of your textbook, etc., or some model?

No. (My actual textbooks were on paper and in a different language anyway.) Why? A typical textbook is about $20,000$ times longer than a comment and as many times harder to read, and you only need one tiny bit of information.

First, consider that all electrons have quantized levels, i.e., each electron has sets of levels. In even the simplest case, hydrogen, has many levels for it's lone electron.
Second, when an electron is forced to a higher level, whether by bombardment with a photon or particle, electrostatic field, or otherwise, it absorbs energy.
Third, when the electron drops down to a lower level, it emits energy, often as a photon. That is the basis of fluorescence, phosphorescence, etc.
In dropping from level 2 to 1 (ground) state, there is but one path. In dropping from level 3, it might go directly to 1 or first two, then one, emitting two photons. From level 4, it has three paths to ground, usw. These are the various emission series (Paschen, Lyman, etc.).
When a comparatively low energy photon (e.g., blue light, UV-A) hits an atom, it does not have sufficient energy to raise an inner electron to a higher level, though it might he=ave enough to raise a valence electron to a metastable state (as in $\ce{AgI}$ photography), or even eject it.
However, when more energetic photons (e.g., X-rays, gamma rays) strike an atom, they can interact with deeper electrons, as well as with the outer shell. Depending on probability, and possible resonance effects, many electrons might be affected... or just one. The text is poorly worded, it it states, "The X-Ray Beam Intercepts the Entire Atom and Chooses to Excite the Hidden and More State [sic] Inner Electron." Hopefully, that was your interpretation of the text.

I think some of the wording of some things gets in the way; I am a visual learner, and I know that increasingly higher sciences have less effective models, so these visuals begin to clash. So if I am understanding correctly, we can completely ignore the idea that an electron is ejected, atleast as far as XRF is concerned? As the other comments have said, should I also assume that that the energy of the sample is conserved; i.e. that the electrons all stay within the sample and do not jump off and leave the system, as far as XRF is concerned?


An ejected electron is simply in a very high orbital. 2. Yes, for a thin sample, electrons can be ejected, leaving a net positive charge on the substrate. This is also the principle of the "beta battery," or betavoltaic cell (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betavoltaic_device).


Should be the last question. I assume that this principle is not relevant to the excitation caused in standard XRD/XRF samples?

An ejected electron is not quantized (in an orbital) following ejection, otherwise it'd be bound.

@BuckThorn, yes, theoretically, an ejected electron is in one of infinitely many higher states. Like the "sea" of electrons in a metal, the Pauli exclusion principle states that each is in it's own level -- though for practical purposes, one assumes a continuum, rather than discrete quantized levels.

I don't know that there is any sense in using a quantum number to describe a free state. I suppose the quantum number would describe the kinetic energy as a multiple of hbar (times a frequency, presumably related to the DeBroglie wavelength), a practically nonsensical amount.

Better than my previous comment, from Wikipedia: "The eigenvalue spectrum is infinitely degenerate since for each eigenvalue E>0, there corresponds an infinite number of eigenfunctions corresponding to different directions of p." My interpretation of "infinite degeneracy" is that it is practically impossible for two electrons simultaneously emitted from the same atom to even try to violate the Pauli principle.
